Wordpress hook for _load_textdomain_just_in_time warning
As no doubt you're aware an error is thrown in Wordpress 6.7 in wp-includes
"Function _load_textdomain_just_in_time was called incorrectly."
This is called on line 6114.
It's a bit annoying on local and staging sites where debugging is on. And plugin authors are slow to address it.
It can be defeated by
if (! str_contains($message, '_load_textdomain_just_in_time') ) {
    trigger_error($message, $error_level);
}

There's a hook in the function wp_trigger_error( $function_name, $message, $error_level = E_USER_NOTICE ), do_action( 'wp_trigger_error_run', $function_name, $message, $error_level );
In my functions.php I have
add_filter( 'wp_trigger_error_run', 'suppress_text_domain_error', 999, 2 );

function suppress_text_domain_error( $message, $error_level) {
    echo "do something";
}

where 'do something' is the amended function call with the modification. But it doesn't remove the original function call.
I've tried adding remove_action but I believe this simply defeats the hook. How do I overwrite the function using this hook (if I can)?
I have read the documentation but there's something fundamental I'm not grasping about hooks.

You could try to first remove the action with remove_action and then use add_action to add your modified version (Copy the original code of the callback and add your condition that hides only that error that annoys you).

Temporarily use the following until a fix appears: add_filter('doing_it_wrong_trigger_error', '__return_false');

@Ferris This doesn't seem to work.I tried it with low and high priority.,

Strangely; changing the dashboard language to English (US) makes the error go away.
